# Rails Active Admin - Ajax post signs me out?

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

In one of my **Active Admin** index pages, I list some records in a table.

I've added the **jQuery sortable** plugin to be able to sort the records by dragging the items vertically. This works fine, and the position attribute for every records updates correctly (via ajax).

Though, if I refresh **Active Admin** after the ajax call, I get signed out and have to login again.

Ajax sends this data:

```
faq[]=1&faq[]=3&faq[]=2
```

The sort method:

```
  def sort
    params[:faq].each_with_index do |id, index|
      Faq.update_all({position: index+1}, {id: id})
    end
    render nothing: true
  end
```

The ajax response is empty and doesn't give any exception.

Why I am signed out?

Answer (score 0):

I had to add the `X-CSRF-Token` to the ajax headers for some reason. I'm not sure why. Shouldn't rails.js do that for me?

Working solution:

```
  $.ajax({
    url: "/faqs/sort",
    type: "post",
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
      xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'));
    },
    data: $(this).sortable('serialize')
  });
```